# Доступ к элементу по нескольким атрибутам, в том числе атрибутам родительского элемента

Tags: html, jquery, input, find

Есть такой элемент

```
<ul my-data-id = 'text1'>
    <li>
        <input value = 'text2'>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input value = 'text3'>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input value = 'text4'>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Мне надо для `input` у которого `value = 'text3'` выставить выбор.

Как можно с помощью jQuery до него корректно добраться через родительский атрибут `my-data-id`?

Т.е. что-то

```
$("ul[my-data-id='text1'] input[value='text3']")
```

?

```js
$("ul[my-data-id='text1'] input[value='text3']").css("color", "red");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul my-data-id='text1'>
  <li>
    <input value='text2'>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input value='text3'>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input value='text4'>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Разве Вы не ответили на свой вопрос? :)

Comment: overthesanity, не сработало, поэтому и написал :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ребята, моя вина :(

Я когда пробовал приведённый код - он не работал, а оказалось я там лишний $ наваял - когда исправил, то всё заработало

**Итого:**

```
$("ul[my-data-id='text1'] input[value='text3']")
```

это и есть решение